# Get data from URL requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to log into a movie streaming website and display the featured movies list. To log in I need to insert 3 dynamic values. This is what I have so far:

```
import requests

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/533.32'
}

data = {
    'audience': 'https://play.tv2.dk',
    'connection': 'TV-2-AWS-Login',
    'password': password,
    'redirect_uri': 'https://play.tv2.dk/api/user/logincallback',
    'response_type': 'code',
    'scope': 'openid email offline_access',
    'tenant': 'tv2dk-prod',
    'username': email,
    '_intstate': 'deprecated'
}

response = requests.get('https://play.tv2.dk/api/user/login?return_url=/', headers=headers)

# first dynamic value
data['_csrf'] = response.cookies['_csrf']
```

I need to load to more values. The `client id` and the `state`. When I open `https://play.tv2.dk/api/user/login?return_url=/` on my regular browser I get this:

`https://auth.tv2.dk/login?state=&client=c2UwaVTTDb7HoLZgK48fu3UDAipgg&protocol=oauth2&audience=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.tv2.dk&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.tv2.dk%2Fapi%2Fuser%2Flogincallback&scope=openid%20email%20offline_access#/`

This URL contains the `cliend id` I'm just wondering how can I parse and grab the client id and how can I get the `state` value

Comment: `from urllib import parse;    print(dict(parse.parse_qsl(parse.urlsplit(url).query)));` this will print you a dictionary of values in query, then you just get from this dict value by key `client_id`.

Comment: @Arty that didn't work it just returned the web pages source. The ```client id``` isn't there.

Comment: @Vova in params

Comment: @joker56 I thought it is `client_id` but key is actually called `client`, see [code here](https://tio.run/##dVBNa8MwDL33VwRG0uaSjGSwshFGoYzBdmx32CU4tpKIOpZryxv59ZkXeh3o6z14T0J25pFMvSy9oykJTmvsEpwsOU6scB42kUuaZDsyW/9UliLwWPB3VahLqWlA8@JZMDSZ1AiGG1mdf8Tn6XTsHt/o42t4f9j3oT4fD2iHIbOOmCTphv58qkwEFVUSmtU@rQ9p9RrDajHflmQOvCXjoeXZQiNJQaQUOpDcBof/KyMSFmMNHlxs67VSaN0Jecm8pGgX06BKq3uYBOrYqe81GmiFlOD9XbndWIeGdwol79aHFGttr17fcHyQtxp5F4e8uAZwc57nz8vyCw), look at output window, key `client` is there, it is what you're looking for probably. `state` is not there if it is empty.

Comment: @Arty well yes that works if you supply the URL. But the URL itself is dynamic. Notice the client id in this URL: ```https://auth.tv2.dk/login?state=&client=c2UwaVTTDb7HoLZgK48fu3UDAipgg&protocol=oauth2&audience=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.tv2.dk&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.tv2.dk%2Fapi%2Fuser%2Flogincallback&scope=openid%20email%20offline_access#/``` It's not static. So I can't send that URL without knowing what the client id is first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like that:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://auth.tv2.dk/login?state=&client=c2UwaVTTDb7HoLZgK48fu3UDAipgg&protocol=oauth2&audience=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.tv2.dk&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.tv2.dk%2Fapi%2Fuser%2Flogincallback&scope=openid%20email%20offline_access#/'

o = urlparse(url)
parsed = dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(o.query))
print(parsed)
```

seems like there's already solution in comments, below question, but anyway that one might help someone

Comment: This returns: ```%7B%22audience%22%3A%20%22https%3A//play.tv2.dk%22%2C%20%22connection%22%3A%20%22TV-2-AWS-Login%22%2C%20%22password%22%3A%20%22password%22%2C%20%22redirect_uri%22%3A%20%22https%3A//play.tv2.dk/api/user/logincallback%22%2C%20%22response_type%22%3A%20%22code%22%2C%20%22scope%22%3A%20%22openid%20email%20offline_access%22%2C%20%22tenant%22%3A%20%22tv2dk-prod%22%2C%20%22username%22%3A%20%22email%22%2C%20%22_intstate%22%3A%20%22deprecated%22%7D``` Where's the ```state``` and ```client id```? Can't I just parse them from a URL and add them to a dict instead?So that I can post my data

Comment: later one once I have all the required parameters in my data dictionary